# How do I install Awesome Windows Manager in Terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, software-installation, awesome

Right now I'm running on Kubuntu and I'd like to install Awesome Window Manager in terminal. I've used Xmonad but I'd like another window manager, but don't know how to install "Awesome" from the terminal.

Answer (score 9):

awesome is in the repositories, so

```
sudo apt-get install awesome fonts-font-awesome awesome-extra
```

For additional information see http://laputa.io/blog/2012/09/02/using-awesome-in-ubuntu-12.04/ , http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/901758-how-to-awesome-wm-with-debianubuntu/ and the awesome documentation

http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Main_Page

http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/

Comment: you are most welcome